# Storing reader item in array

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim myReader As OleDbDataReader
Dim Index As Integer
Dim status As Array
Index = 0
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CPALLOCATIONTIME from RECORDMASTER where ID='" & TxtID.Text & "'"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

Do While myReader.Read()
     status(Index) = myReader.Item(0)
     Index = Index + 1
Loop

myReader.Close()

If (Index = 2) Then
If ((status(0) = "Fp" Or status(0) = "Op") And status(1) = "OXp") Then
    qText = TxtSTS.Text + "X"
    Update = True
    ApplicationStatus = 2
ElseIf ((status(0) = "Fp" Or status(0) = "Op") And status(1) = "FXp") Then
    qText = TxtSTS.Text + "X"
    Update = True
    ApplicationStatus = 2
End If
```

Can some one please help me with  `status(Index) = myReader.Item(0)`, giving an error with conversion

Answer (score 1):

1. You want your array to *grow* as elements are added. That's not what arrays are for. Use a `List(Of T)` instead. (See the [examples on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) for the exact syntax.)
2. Make sure the data read from the reader has the correct data type. You have two ways of doing that:

   1. Cast it (e.g. `DirectCast(myReader(0), String)`) or
   2. (better) use the reader method that already returns the correct data type, e.g. `myReader.GetString(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
status(Index) = myReader.Item(0).ToString
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Redim status(0) ' < -- declare like this
```

Then in Loop

```
Redim preserve status(index)
status(Index) = myReader("Column_name")
index = index + 1
```